# How to ignore/avoid `self signed certificate error' in AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to do a post request to a server which is using self signed certificate but I am getting self signed certificate error while doing so. Is there a way to avoid or make the JavaScript code to neglect such errors?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function sendToServer(){
     var username, password;

     username = "";
     password = "";

      var xhr;
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
         xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
         xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }

     //creating the xml string
       xmlString = "";
       var url = "";
       xhr.open("POST", url, true);
       xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.emc.apollo-v1+xml");
       xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
       xhr.send(xmlString);

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {  
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
       };
     }

</script>
```

Comment: Import the certificate in your browser's certificate trust store.

Answer (score 0):

Self signed certificates are not trusted by browsers as they are generated by the same server to which the request is made. so you have to configure your browser to trust the certificate. if you are using chrome follow these steps:

1. Visit the site in your browser
2. Click 'View site information' icon (a padlock) in the address bar:
3. Click 'Certificate Information'.
4. On the Details tab, click 'Copy to File' and save the file using defaults.
5. Locate and double-click the certificate file you just saved.
6. On the certificate General tab, click 'Install Certificate'.
7. In the Install Certificate Wizard, select 'Place all certificates in the following store'.
8. Click 'Browse' and select 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities', then continue through the remaining steps to install the certificate.

source: https://www.attachmate.com/documentation/gateway-1-1/gateway-admin-guide/data/fxg_add_untrusted_cert.htm